# Disable Cash on delivery if catalog or cart price rules apply on product

Tags: magento2, discount

I want to disable the cod payment option on checkout for specific products which has any promotion rules apply on it.

How can i achieve it, please give suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can select in `conditions`,  `Payment method is not cash on delivery` in shopping cart price rule.....

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked conditions but there is no such option available